# Line equation With two point

Tags: linear-algebra, slope

I have a situation where I know the two points, let's say $(6, 320)$ and $(8, 450)$. How can I get the value at any point between these two points?

$($Level$,$ Discharge$)$

$(1, 100)$

$(2, 130)$

$(3, 160)$

$(4, 220)$

$(5, 270)$

$(6, 320)$

$(8, 450)$

Thanks.

[Image about calculating water level at different levels. Please have a look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojm5J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your set of points, you need to create a line of best fit. This can be done by taking any two points in your set of data and creating a line of the form of $y=mx+b$. For example, using $(6, 320)$ and $(8, 450)$ as your two points, we get $m=\frac{450-320}{8-6}=\frac{130}{2}=65$. Now we have $y=65x+b$. To solve for $b$, we can use one of our two points. $320=65(6)+b\Rightarrow b=-70$. So, our equation to find the value between $6$ and $8$ is $y=65x-70$.

Using software, it is easier to find a line of best fit that can represent a line for all of your data points (for example, if you have a TI graphing calculator, you can use their linear regression mode to do this. For your set of points, a line of best fit I got from Mathematica is $y=50.3279x+27.2131$.

Comment: how can i calculate the value

Comment: @Rawat, sorry about my previous answer. I originally misread your question. Here is the updated answer.

Comment: thanks i never done these linear equation but for some reason i need to calculate this,  how can i get a value for point suppose  y is 7.5

Comment: @Rawat, to find the point when $y=7.5$, we can take our vector and combine it into one final vector $<x,y,z>=<11+t,6+2t,320+130t>$. We know that $y=6+2t$, so we set $6+2t=7.5$. Then you can solve for $t$ and plug that into $x=11+t$ for your $x$ value and into $z=320+130t$ for your $z$ value.

Comment: this is something like we are getting calculating the percentage from 450-320 like 6.5 is 25 % of 130 and add to 320 will be the value at 6.5, i have added a pic in my question please have a look

Comment: sorry for the information can you give some info about this we have values of these points at database but for particular point like at 6 we have 320 level and at 8 we have 450 but how can i calculate at between these points

Comment: its like water level at different points 6 is y value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55807/discussion-between-rawat-and-jonathan-barkey).

Comment: this solution is still giving the same result like at y value 8 discharge is 450 and at y value 6 discharge is 320 difference is 130 so at point 7 discharge will be 65 just half of 130 but that not gonna happen

Answer (score 0):

First step .- Define your point

$$\dfrac{x-11}{y-6}=\dfrac{12-11}{8-6}$$

Second step .- Calculate distance from point (11,6)

$$LT=\sqrt{(12-11)^2+(8-6)^2}$$

$$Lxy=\sqrt{(x-11)^2+(y-6)^2}$$

Third step .- Calculate the VALUE for (x,y)

$LT->(450-320)$

$Lxy->(VALUE-320)$

$$VALUE = ...$$